# How to replace the characters in one table to the records of another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have two tables in MSACCESS.

table1

**table1ID,txtOld,txtreplace,country**

1,ä,AA,Germany

2,ä,a,all

3,Ä,A,Norway

4,Ä,a,all

5,Ä,A,Germany

table2

**table2ID,FirstName,Address,country**

1,RonÄld, mäin street,Germany

2,MÄdonä, park way, USA

3,Madonä, park way, Norway

I want to replace the special characters on firstname and address on table2 on the basis of the country characters assigned on table1. If the country doesn't match or not assigned on table1 for eg here USA is not assigned it will replace the characters matched with country name "all" from table1.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we cannot do this in a single Access SQL query, so we use VBA:

[image]

```
Sub ReplaceAccentsInTable2()
'
  Dim rst As dao.Recordset
  Dim rst1 As dao.Recordset
'
  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("table2")
'
' replace first by country specific alphabet:
'
  Do While (Not rst.EOF)
    '
    Set rst1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT txtOld, txtreplace" _
      & " FROM table1 WHERE (country='" & rst!Country & "');")
    '
    rst.Edit
    '
    While (Not rst1.EOF)
      rst!Firstname = Replace(rst!Firstname, rst1!txtOld, rst1!txtreplace, , , vbBinaryCompare)
      rst!Address = Replace(rst!Address, rst1!txtOld, rst1!txtreplace, , , vbBinaryCompare)
      rst1.MoveNext
    Wend
    '
    rst.Update
    rst.MoveNext
    '
  Loop
'
' replace then "all" alphabet: this is useful for Norway, as â is not set in table1:
'
  Set rst1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT txtOld, txtreplace" _
    & " FROM table1 WHERE (country='all');")
'
  rst.MoveFirst
'
  Do While (Not rst.EOF)
    '
    rst.Edit
    rst1.MoveFirst
    '
    While (Not rst1.EOF)
      rst!Firstname = Replace(rst!Firstname, rst1!txtOld, rst1!txtreplace, , , vbBinaryCompare)
      rst!Address = Replace(rst!Address, rst1!txtOld, rst1!txtreplace, , , vbBinaryCompare)
      rst1.MoveNext
    Wend
    '
    rst.Update
    rst.MoveNext
    '
  Loop

'
' close ADO objects:
'
  rst1.Close
  Set rst1 = Nothing
'
  rst.Close
  Set rst = Nothing
'
End Sub
```

The result table2 here:

[image]